# Reading options inside a function and return it as a value

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

I'm trying to write a function which will parse my arguments. Here is how it looks like:

```
opts_get(){
    CONFIG=()
    while getopts "f:" opt; do
        case $opt in
            f)
                CONFIG=$OPTARG
                ;;
            :)
                echo "Option -$OPTARG requires argument" 1>&2
                exit 1
                ;;
            \?)
                echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" 1>&2
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
    done
    echo $CONFIG
}

echo $(opts_get)
```

But unfortunately it prints empty line even if I pass the `-f sdf` option.

If I put the reading option code outside of any function

```
CONFIG=()
while getopts "f:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            CONFIG=$OPTARG
            ;;
        :)
            echo "Option -$OPTARG requires argument" 1>&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" 1>&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
echo $CONFIG #prints what I want
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the arguments the function. You need to pass it from the script to the function as below.

```
echo $(opts_get "$@")
```

The 2<sup>nd</sup> case worked because the positional arguments form the command line are directly read by `getopts`. Also do fix the variable initialization to just `CONFIG=""` and not as an array declaration.

You also need to make sure that `${OPTIND}` is local to the function by either unsetting it or declaring it local, otherwise you will encounter unexpected behaviour when invoking the function multiple times.

Comment: So if the function is called from another function. I should pass the parameters to the caller function first, right?

Comment: What do you mean $`{OPTIND}`?

Comment: @St.Antario: Yes absolutely

Comment: @St.Antario: It contains the index of the next argument to be processed, if you are just using one, no issues with it